# Javascript: indexOf

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to search for a value in a string.

```
if (myValue.indexOf("Call") > -1) {
 //dosomething
}
```

How can I do and or?

```
(myValue.indexOf("Call" || "Data") > -1)
```

The following works;

```
if (myValue.indexOf("Call") > -1 || (myValue.indexOf("Data") > -1) ) {
     //dosomething
    }
```

But i thought there was an easier way?

Comment: have you tried using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way :

```
myValue.match(/(Call)|(Data)/ig)
```

Comment: `i = ignore case` & `g = global`. Optional, Just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
if (myValue.indexOf("Call") > -1  || myValue.indexOf("Data") > -1) {
  //dosomething
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
if ((myValue.indexOf("Call") > -1) || (myValue.indexOf("Data") > -1)) {
 //dosomething
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use indexOf like that.

You either use two separate calls to indexOf

```
(myValue.indexOf("Call") > -1 || myValue.indexOf("Data") > -1)
```

Or you can use RegExp

```
RegExp("Call|Data$").exec(myValue) != null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression.

```
String.prototype.regexIndexOf = function (regex, startpos) {
    var indexOf = this.substring(startpos || 0).search(regex);
    return (indexOf >= 0) ? (indexOf + (startpos || 0)) : indexOf;
}

var myValue = 'Lieutenant Commander Data';

if (myValue.regexIndexOf(/(Call)|(Data)/g) > -1) {
    alert('Success');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var bool = (myValue.indexOf("Call") > -1 ||  myValue.indexOf("Data") > -1);
```